# after node 6.7.0 release, do we still need babel to compile es6 code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

at the latest node release, the engine supports the 98% of the ES standards, my question is that can we run the code without compiling the code with babel to ES5

Comment: You will soon need it for ES7 anyway, best to keep the habit of using it

Comment: Presumably so long as you avoid the 2%....?

Comment: The answer seems obvious. No, if you use the 98% that are supported. What kind of response to you expect here?

Comment: "can we run the code" What code? Which ES features are you using in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript standard is continuously being developed, with new features being added yearly. Node.js now supports 97% of the ES2015 (previously named ES6) specification, so if those features are the ones you are going to use, then you should be fine.

But the ES2016 specification is already out, and the ES2017 specification is already well underway, so if you want to use *future* JavaScript features that Node does not support yet, you will have to use Babel (or some other transplier).

Another thing to consider is if you want to use ES2015+ features, but want to support *older* versions of Node, for instance if you're writing a library, then you will also need to use a transplier like Babel.

**In summary:**

- If you want to use JavaScript features not yet supported by Node.js (ES2016+), use Babel.
- If you want to support older versions of Node.js while still using modern JavaScript features (ES2015+), use Babel.
- Otherwise, you don't need to use Babel.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, as long as you remember about the remaining 2%.
Babel is much more useful in browsers. For Node apps - not so much.